# Use Dependency Injected Services in AutoMapper Profile

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, automapper

I have an AfterMap method that needs to use the context to change the EntityState of some elements as well as to use the injected mapper instance to map related data on top of existing data as a modification, not an addition.

My issue is, I cannot get dependency injection inside of the profile. If I define a profile like this:

`public MyProfile(IMapper mapper, MyContext context)`

It errors when trying to add the profile that there isn't a constructor with no parameters. My configuration in startup is this:

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.AddMaps("MYAPP");
            });
            services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(x => mapperConfig.CreateMapper());
```

How can I inject dependencies into these profiles to use in my AfterMap Methods.

Profile example for reference:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile {
IMapper _mapper;
MyContext _context;
public MyProfile(IMapper mapper, MyContext context) {
_mapper = mapper;
_context = context;

CreateMap<Thing1, Thing2>()
        .ForMember(d => d.IncidentCauseSubTypes, o => o.Ignore())
        .AfterMap((src, dest) => MergeRelatedLists(Things1, Thing2, _mapper, _context));
}

}
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Before-and-after-map-actions.html#using-imappingaction

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu finally stumbled on that myself too. If you want to formulate the IMappingActions suggestion into a full answer, I'll accept.